# WebBrowser get page size

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

When working with WebBrowser on IE 9 and above the property

```
webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Size
```

returns always 250 x 250 as body dimensions.
Therefore I can't come across a way to check the current page size.

How can I check a html page actual size using IE 9 and above?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that seemed to work all the time until now.

I hope it'll help people with the same problem as I do, as you might have figured out in IE 9 or above, the Body element contains the default size for the ScrollRectangle property, however, as I found out, some other elements do contain the ScrollRectangle property with different sizes.

Most certainly that the HTML element contains a correct ScrollRectangle property, but some other elements might contain a ScrollRectangle greater or smaller in size, and sometimes it fits better.

So I've come to a conclusion that checking all the elements for the ScrollRectangle property is the smartest thing to do, here's the script :

```
int
    CurrentWidth
    , CurrentHeight
    , CurrentMinWidth = WebBrowserOuterPanel.Width
    , CurrentMaxWidth = 0
    , CurrentMinHeight = WebBrowserOuterPanel.Height
    , CurrentMaxHeight = 0;

foreach(HtmlElement webBrowserElement in webBrowser.Document.All)
{
    if ((CurrentWidth = Math.Max(webBrowserElement.ClientRectangle.Width, webBrowserElement.ScrollRectangle.Width)) > CurrentMaxWidth)
        CurrentMaxWidth = CurrentWidth;

    if ((CurrentHeight = Math.Max(webBrowserElement.ClientRectangle.Height, webBrowserElement.ScrollRectangle.Height)) > CurrentMaxHeight)
        CurrentMaxHeight = CurrentHeight;
}

webBrowser.Size = new Size (CurrentMaxWidth > CurrentMinWidth ? CurrentMaxWidth : CurrentMinWidth, CurrentMaxHeight > CurrentMinHeight ? CurrentMaxHeight : CurrentMinHeight);
```

Another way but might be not correct, in idea for implementing

```
HtmlElement webBrowserElement = webBrowser.Document.Body.FirstChild;

CurrentMaxWidth = Math.Max(webBrowserElement.ClientRectangle.Width, webBrowserElement.ScrollRectangle.Width);

CurrentMaxHeight = Math.Max(webBrowserElement.ClientRectangle.Height, webBrowserElement.ScrollRectangle.Height);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the window size

`webBrowser.Document.Window.Size`

Comment: So you could try this: `WebBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Size` and if that doesn't work its possible that the page finished rendering yet and might need to use DocumentComplete

Comment: you can watch my solution for next time someone asks this question, if you may. thanks for the willing to help.