# Location of an element in a WebBrowser c#

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF project that loads a WebBrowser property, now I want to know the pixelized location of a specific element in the WebBrowser property, and to focus/zoom to that element in the program, so that the user will be able to see what is going on visually.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

Create a panel that includes the WebBrowser control and size the WebBrowser control to its content size (a how to can be found in my last question, here : [WebBrowser get page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638984/webbrowser-get-page-size)), so now the WebBrowser control has no scroll in it, but the panel has one (if the panel size is smaller than the current WebBrowser control size).

Next step is scrolling to an element, and the following code does it :

```
SomePanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(SomeWebBrowserElement.OffsetRectangle.X, SomeWebBrowserElement.OffsetRectangle.Y);
```

And that does it.

Hope it helps those who seek the same thing.

Edit :

P.S.

Some of you might wanna become fancy with the scroll wheels and make it scroll to that the element will be in the middle of the screen, since the location makes it in top left, that's possible too, just use the panel size in order to do that.